# Add space between list items, or make items easier to select on touchscreens in ASP.NET dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, user-interface

When developing an ASP.NET web application that is targeted at mobile devices (mainly tablets), I've noticed that drop down lists are sometimes difficult for users to select the correct item if they have fat fingers, or just aren't very good with a touchscreen.

I know I'm not the only one to notice this, as IOS apps specifically moved away from using drop downs for this reason and instead they typically use that UIPickerView control that looks like a roll of toilet paper, but lets people more easily select an item from a list by scrolling.

So, I'm looking for a good way in ASP.NET, without rolling my own custom control, to either make a dropdownlist easier to use on mobile devices, or am looking for some free control that I could use in place of a dropdownlist.

The first thing that comes to mind is; can I somehow space the list items further apart, so people can more easily select the item they intended?  I've tried changing the font to be bigger, but that doesn't really help; especially because then the control has to be wider, when the problem is really just how much vertical space there is between items.

If not, does anyone have any suggestions or real-life examples of how they've addressed this concern?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [DropKick.js](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) in passed projects with success. It overcomes the shortfalls of styling select options and provides more control of styling through CSS.

**Update** *(after comment)*:

DropKick.js [progressively enhances](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) the HTML (select field) that's rendered on the page. All you'd need to do is provide the proper hooks that dropkick needs to convert the rendered select field into its implementation.

*From dropkicks' homepage:*

> How to use
>
> DropKick works by transforming your existing, boring  into
>   beautiful, customizable HTML dropdowns. The name attribute is the only
>   one that is required. You should also set a tabindex attribute to
>   enable navigation via tabbing.
>
> ```
> <select name="pretty" tabindex="1" class="pretty dk">
>   <option value="">Choose a reaction</option>
>   <option value="amazed">Amazed</option>
>   <option value="bored">Bored</option>
>   <option value="surprised">Surprised</option>
> </select>
> ```

### How do I use it in asp.net

Pretty simple you can download the js file and include it in your site:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropkick.js"></script>`

And include the css files for the styling:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">`

You're almost there...now you need to use jquery to add it to the page's drop down lists, something to this effect:

`$('#myDropDown').dropkick();`

Or

`$('.myDropDown').dropkick();`

Comment: Seems promising, but how to use it with ASP.NET?  I mean, I need to be able to populate the drop downs from my ASP.NET code behind, and I need to be able to see the selected value in my ASP.NET code behind too (I suppose the latter can be done by populating the selected value in a hidden field with javascript).

Comment: @Jim-its just a `js` file you can include it in your asp.net page and then add a name property to your drop down box.  Very nice +1.

Comment: @JonH right. though, in aspnet webforms the `name` attribute is usually the same as the `id` server attribute of the `dropdownlist`. nonetheless, that's the idea.

Comment: Some advice about this..before you use it understand the ramifications it presents.  You can no longer easily type in a letter to get right to a drop down list item.  The library doesn't allow that.  So if you have a drop down list with three items `Blue, Bluey, Bar` and in standard asp.net dropdownlist box you can begin typing `ba` it takes you right to `bar`.  But if you implement this js solution you can no longer do that.  Not so bad if you are dealing with small lists, but if you have lists of users for instance and there are plenty of them..then no one will like this solution.

Comment: @Jim - I've added an example of how to use it in asp.net.

Comment: Aweson stuff, thanks everyone, I'll definitely try it out to see if it fits my needs. @Jon H, good point, but for my purposes on a mobile device, it's all about picking the right list item with your finger on a touchscreen, so this looks great! +1s all around!

Comment: Marking this as accepted, as it does address my question quite nicely, and noone else has yet provided any examples of how to they've tackled this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use CSS. If you want to get fancy with JS, you can probably even serve different stylesheets according to the browser's user agent (desktop vs. mobile).

```
/* Drop down control itself */
select.ddlList {
    padding: 5px; /* padding between the border of the drop down and the items */
}
/* Drop down list items */
select.ddlList > option {
    padding: 15px 5px; /* 15px = top/bottom padding, 5px = left/right padding */
}
```

With an ASP.NET control...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" CssClass="ddlList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem ... />
    <asp:ListItem ... />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

---

Edit: Well, Xander is right--you can't style the options via CSS, but my example for the DropDownList styling still stands. This will make your DropDownList much more visible to a touch client. http://jsfiddle.net/DwY87/6/